# C format strings questions

Tags: c, printf, string-formatting, ternary-operator

I'm still learning C and trying to understand some of what I'm seeing in the follow:

```
printf("%s ", row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL");
```

Obviously, I'm aware of `printf`, `%s` etc. What I don't grasp fully is what I should look for to understand the `? :` and what my other options are. I'm not familiar with the terminology, so I'm not even certain this is part of "format strings". What I'm ASSUMING this it is returning `row[i]` and continuing to return `row[i]` until it hits a `NULL`?

Clarification and a pointer in the right direction to learn and understand this a bit better would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: ?: is ternary operator http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C

Answer (score 3):

It has nothing to do with string formatting. It's a piece of syntactic sugar called a *ternary operation*. It looks like this: `<condition> ? <if_true> : <if_false>`.
Expanded, it is equivalent to this:

```
if (row[i])
{
    result = row[i];
}
else
{
    result = "NULL";
}

printf("%s ", result);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is called the trenary operator. If the statement is `<condition> ? <res1> : <res2>`, then if `condition` is evaluated as true, the statement is evaluated as `res1`, otherwise as `res2`.

Comment: ternary, not trenay. And it's more precisly called the "condtional operator"; it's referred to as the "ternary operator" only because it happens to be the only operator in the language that takes three operands.

Answer (score 1):

The `?` operator is something called a [conditional operator](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/operators/ternary-operator.html) (or ternary operator). It can be thought of as an "in-line conditional statement". The code you've shared is equivalent to:

```
if(row[i] != NULL) {
  printf("%s ", row[i]);
} else {
  printf("%s ", "NULL");
}
```

Conditional operators can be used as arguments to functions or assignments. They follow the following syntax:

```
[conditional boolean evaluation] ? [value if true] : [value if false]
```

So, you can embed that like in the example below:

```
int y = x < 5 ? 1 : 0;   // if x is less than 5, y will be 1, otherwise it will be zero
```

Comment: Thank you - I had a feeling that's what it was doing, but I wasn't familiar with conditional operators and was completely unaware they could be used in this manner. Seems it cuts the code down significantly ... I'll have to do some more reading on operators. Thank you.